# C++ Program for Specific Triangle Pattern

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to form the triangle pattern shown by "target" and I got the one labeled "actual output." I am also only supposed to use nested for loops and the % operator. I have tried playing around with the % operator and i or j in addition to k or instead of k, but I haven't been able to fully get the pattern I am looking for. It looks like my odd rows are good (row 1, 3, 5) but everything is not. Any help is welcome.

```
// target: * + * + * +      actual output:   * + * + * +    
             + * + * +                         * + * + *
               * + * +                           * + * +
                 + * +                             * + *
                   * +                               * +
                     +                                 *
//
// code //
int main ()
{
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 6; i >= 1; i--
    {
      for (j = 1;j <= (6 - i); j++ )
      {
          cout << " ";
      }


       for (k = 1;k<=i;k++)
       {
        if (k % 2 == 0) {



        cout << "+"; 


        }
        else
        {
         cout << "*";
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Do not use additional variable `k` wich always started from `1`. Just continue to use `j` incrementing it up to `6`. `for ( ; j <= 6; j++) if (j % 2) ...`

Comment: you can also take into account the value of i, not only k, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace

```
if (k % 2 == 0)
```

by

```
if ((k+i) % 2 == 0)
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i,j,k;
  for (i = 6; i >= 1; i--)
  {
    for (j = 1;j <= (6 - i); j++ )
    {
      cout << " ";
    }

    for (k = 1;k<=i;k++)
    {
      if ((k+i) % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "+"; 
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "*";
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra t.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
*+*+*+
 +*+*+
  *+*+
   +*+
    *+
     +
```

Answer (score 0):

(based on my comment)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; ++j )
        {
            cout << ' ';
        }
        for ( ; j < 6; ++j) // just carry on to increment j
        {
            cout << (j % 2 ? '+' : '*');
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```